# Test catalogs - common bugs or test cases

Tags: testing, catalog

I'm looking for catalogs of common bugs, weaknesses, and test cases or questions for software.  In *Lessons Learned in Software Testing* I saw an example test catalog, but I typically can't find good, specific test catalogs out there for various common features or feature types.  Can someone point me to a resource?

Perhaps a community wiki on SO would be in order?

Here are some comminuty wikis for test case catalogs:

- [Numeric Input Test Catalog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3153782/test-catalog-items-for-numeric-input)
- [Text Input Test Catalog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3283104/test-cases-for-string-inputs)

Comment: I found this list via hacker news:  https://github.com/minimaxir/big-list-of-naughty-strings

Answer (score 4):

Here's a great starting point:

Elisabeth Hendrickson and others put together this [Test Heuristics Cheat Sheet](http://testobsessed.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2007/02/testheuristicscheatsheetv1.pdf) (this links to a PDF). I always use it for building out test cases and looking at what I might have missed.

Comment: aaah, now **that** brings back memories. No way to top that.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a good link with stuff that's easy to forget to test
http://www.thebraidytester.com/downloads/YouAreNotDoneYet.pdf