# Test cases for numeric input

Tags: testing, numbers, catalog

What are some common (or worthwhile) tests, test questions, weaknesses, or misunderstandings dealing with numeric inputs?

*This is a community wiki.  Please add to it.*

For example, here are a couple sample ideas:

- I commonly see users enter text into number fields (e.g., ">4" or "4 days", etc).
- Fields left blank (null)
- Very long numeric strings
- Multiple decimals and commas (e.g., "4..4" and "4,,434.4.4")
- Boundary Value Analysis:

  - Lower Boundary
  - Lower Boundary - 1 (for decimal/float, use smaller amounts)
  - Upper Boundary
  - Upper Boundary + 1
  - Far below the lower boundary (e.g., beyond the hardware boundary value)
  - Far above the upper boundary
  - middle of the range
- 0
- 0.0
- Whitespace, nothing else "   "
- Whitespace before, in, or after an otherwise valid number
- String input & other incorrect data types.
- Number with text in front or back, e.g. "$5.00", "4 lbs", "about 60", "50+"
- Negative numbers
- + sign with positive numbers, "+4"
- Both plus and minus sign, e.g. "+-4" and "-4e+30"
- Exponents of 10, both uppercase and lowercase, positive and negative e.g. "4e10", "-5E-10", "+6e+60", etc
- Too many "e" characters, e.g. "4e4e4" "4EE4"
- Impossibly large/small exponents or inappropriate ones
- Decimal values that cannot be represented in a computer

  - e.g. .3 + .6 == 1.0?  This bug affects most hardware, so outputs that compare decimal values should allow for a degree of error.
- Integer/hardware overflow.  e.g., for 32-bit integers, what happens when adding 4 billion to 4 billion?
- Wrong use of decimal sign and thousands separator ("," vs. ".") (MikeD)
- Internationalisation i18n issues: In English applications you write "12,345.67" meaning "12345.67" in German you write "12345,67" – (k3b)
- Leading 0's don't make number octal (common JavaScript bug)

Comment: what about internationalisation [Tag:i18n] issues? in english aplications you write "12,345.67" meaning "12345.67" in german you write "12345,67"

Comment: @k3b, good one.  This is a community wiki, so you can add it to the list above (you should see an edit link below the tags).  If you want me to add it for you, that's fine.

Comment: when i wrote the comment i had not the required 100 reputation points to edit wiki. now i have got more than 100 and added it to wiki :-)