# Test cases for string inputs

Tags: testing, wiki, testcase

What are some useful test case ideas (and test questions) related to **string inputs?**  Usefulness need not mean applicable everywhere or all the time--just often enough to be worth considering when you address a new problem/system/domain.

Individual answers may contain questions specific to certain domains (eg email address) but should probably point to a separate wiki-question.

Please add your answer BOTH to the question and to the list of answers so that individual items may be voted upon.

Some answers:

- See https://github.com/minimaxir/big-list-of-naughty-strings
- Blank/null string
- Whitespace only
- All ASCII/ANSI characters 0-255
- Extended Ascii characters (e.g. in Outlook)
- Very long strings (suggest using perlclip to generate a counterstring, eg 2*4*6*8*11*14*17*20*
- Only one character
- Unicode characters
- SQL injection
- Cross-site scripting, Cross-site request forgery
- [ReDos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3283104/test-cases-for-string-inputs/3283117#3283117)

Related SO Questions:

- [Other test catalogs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3153697/test-catalogs-common-bugs-or-test-cases)

Comment: https://github.com/minimaxir/big-list-of-naughty-strings

Answer (score 5):

- localization concerns regarding number formats (decimals / commas)
- behavior sensitivity of special characters (for example supporting single quotes, but still being capable of parsing a name like `Jim O'malley`)
- escape character, and ending a string with the escape character - for example if your escape character is `^`, and the user inputs something like `See above^`
- new lines in a string intended as single-line.

the list is endless though because it really depends on how you intend to use the string, and where it came from.

Answer (score 2):

ReDos vulnerabilities if a Regular Expression is used

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff646973.aspx